# Is there a difference between borrowing a reference at declaration time and at argument passing time?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm new to Rust, so apologies if I misused any terminology in the title.

Given the following function:

```rust
fn do_something(i: &i32) {
    println!("{i}");
}
```

Is there a difference between this:

```rust
let a = &5;
do_something(a);
```

and this?

```rust
let b = 5;
do_something(&b);
```

Running the code shows that the two snippets have equivalent behavior, but I have a (very fuzzy) intuition that they result in different objects - one which stores a reference to a value, and another which is a value that we borrow a reference to - and that the borrow checker would let you do different things with them as a result.

Finally, I feel like this should be more or less Google-able, but my Google-fu is completely failing me due to a lack of terminology. For example, would you say the first one is a "reference variable" and the second is a "reference to a variable" or are those also the same thing?

Comment: The difference is that `a` and `b` are different types: `a` is a `&i32` while `b` is an `i32`. As far as `do_something()` is concerned though, there is no difference.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as you can see on the [compiler explorer](https://rust.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:29,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:29,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:29,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:29,startLineNumber:3),source:%27%0Apub+fn+do_something(i:+%26i32)+%7B%0A++++std::hint::black_box(i)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//Is+there+a+difference+between+this:%0Apub+fn+a()+%7B%0Alet+a+%3D+%265%3B%0Ado_something(a)%3B%0A%7D%0A//and+this%3F%0Apub+fn+b()+%7B%0Alet+b+%3D+5%3B%0Ado_something(%26b)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:r1660,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-C++opt-level%3D3%27,selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:23,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:23,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:8),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+rustc+1.66.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) the first version will only store the pointer on the stack while keeping the value in static memory:

```
example::a:
        push    rax
        lea     rax, [rip + .L__unnamed_1]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rax
        mov     rax, rsp
        pop     rax
        ret
```

while the second will store the actual value and the pointer there:

```
example::b:
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], 5
        lea     rax, [rsp + 4]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rax
        lea     rax, [rsp + 8]
        add     rsp, 16
        ret
```